# Recursion to make chord inversions

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I am a composer usually working with Max-MSP and OpenMusic.
For porting some work from OM to Max, I have just started to learn LISP.

My problem is rather simple: I want to make chord inversions from a given chord.

From `(C E G)` it needs to return `((C E G) (E G C) (G C E))`. It means that for a 3 notes chord I'll get 3 inversions and for n notes chord n inversions.

I've already built the basic functions:

```
(defun if-x-under-y-raise-x (x y)
  (if (<= x y) (if-x-under-y-raise-x (+ x 12) y)  x))

(defun transp (chord)
  (append (cdr chord) 
          (cons (if-x-under-y-raise-x (first chord) (list-max chord 0)) nil)))
```

`transp` function takes the lowest note of a sorted chord and transpose it by one octave until it is higher than the highest note of the chord recursively.
So expressed in MIDI it means that `(60 64 67)` becomes `(64 67 72)`. This is very easy to do.

Problems come when I want to get the `n` inversions recursively as explained before.
I can do it once with `transp` but the function below doesn't work:

```
(defun renverse (chords)
  (if (< (length (first chords)) (length chords))
      chords
    (cons chords (renverse (list (transp (last chords)))))))
```

`chords` is the starting list.
`(renverse '(60 64 67))` should return 3 chord inversions.

Any help will be very welcome.
:-)

Comment: `(cons X nil)` is better written as `(list X)`

Comment: `renverse` expects a tree (you are computing `length` of the first element) but in the example you are giving it a simple list. could you please clarify what the function should do.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087693/how-can-i-get-all-possible-permutations-of-a-list-with-common-lisp. As far as I can tell, this is just finding all possible permutations of a list (`(C E G)`) with a possible transposition up/down an octave afterwords.

Comment: @Linuxios - Not exactly; it's finding all _rotations_ of the list, with octavo transpositions.

Comment: @sds yes this is a typing error. I mean '((60 64 67)).

Answer (score 3):

LOOP:

```
(defun renverse (chord)
  (loop for chord0 = chord then (transp chord0)
        repeat (length chord)
        collect chord0))
```

Recursive (with the usual call stack depth limitation):

```
(defun renverse (chord &optional (n (length chord)))
  (cons chord
        (if (= n 1)
            nil
          (renverse (transp chord) (1- n)))))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 19 > (renverse '(60 64 67))
((60 64 67) (64 67 72) (67 72 76))
```

You could also write it in some neutral list processing style:

```
(defun mutate-list-n-times-by-fn (list &key (n (length list)) (fn #'identity))
  (loop for l = list then (funcall fn l)
        repeat n
        collect l))

(defun renverse (chord)
  (mutate-list-n-times-by-fn chord :fn #'transp))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Rainer. Your examples are very helpfull in the present time and inspiring for the future.